# Getting Python System Calls as string results

Tags: python

I'd like to use `os.system("md5sum myFile")` and have the result returned from os.system instead of just runned in a subshell where it's echoed.

In short I'd like to do this:

```
resultMD5 = os.system("md5sum myFile")
```

And only have the md5sum in resultMD5 and not echoed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) is better than using `os.system` or `os.popen`

```
import subprocess
resultMD5 = subprocess.Popen(["md5sum","myFile"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Or just calculate the md5sum yourself with the [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) module.

```
import hashlib
resultMD5 = hashlib.md5(open("myFile").read()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: +1 to hashlib, the best way to do it, not depending of an external executable.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the subprocess module as a replacement for os.system.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: what Douglas Leeder said :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("md5sum gmail.csv", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
resultMD5, filename = p.communicate()[0].split()
print resultMD5
```

Comment: no need to go through the shell to run md5sum. Don't use shell=True